# How do you add large range of NaN columns to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am trying to add nan columns to the end of my dataframe. I have tried this, but it does not seem to work

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

test = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=None)
test.iloc[:,108:203] = np.nan
```

Where 108 through 203 are the new column indices I would like to add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets Try .`reindex()`

```
test.reindex(np.arange(expected last row+1))
```

In your case'

```
test.reindex(np.arange(204))
```

Comment: that works! test.reindex(np.arange(204), axis=1) for columns